# Failed to deploy multi-container app to Heroku via Travis CI

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, travis-ci, heroku-cli

For the past 2 days, I have been consistently trying out different methods of deploying my multi-container app to Heroku via Travis CI. Heroku shows a weird error when I deploy my application from Travis CI.

Here's my

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mysql'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/covid_analysis
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

After deploying with this configuration, my Travis CI [build](https://travis-ci.com/github/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis/builds/176259051) shows a weird error:
[image: build error]

After some Google search, I found a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1081) about this problem, which suggests deploying with entrypoint rather than cmd/command.

Therefore, I did change my `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to `entrypoint: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

This time, Travis [build](https://travis-ci.com/github/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis/builds/176260872) errored like this:
[image: build error]

Here is my latest [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis/blob/master/Dockerfile)
I have Googled a lot of things, and I was not able to find anything that could solve my problem (or even explain why it's not working).
All the builds work fine locally. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis).

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your error comes from the way you are calling `docker-compose run` on Travis CI.</s>

In your `.travis.yml`, the following can be found:

```
script:
- docker-compose run web python manage.py test
```

What your docker-compose tries to do here, is to run the following services:

- web
- python
- manage.py
- test

The only service that exists in your docker-compose however is `web`, so the command fails.

**UPDATE**

My original answer was wrong, I thought `docker-compose run` had similar behavior to `docker-compose up`.

The reason the error occurs after refactoring the `web` service from `command:` to `entrypoint:` in the `docker-compose.yml` is because of the following script in the `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
- docker-compose run web python manage.py test
```

The default behavior of `docker-compose run` is that it passes all the arguments after the specified service (in this case `python manage.py test` comes after `web`), as an override to `command`.

Because it is now refactored to `entrypoint`, this does not work anymore. This can be fixed by writing the script like this:

```
script:
- docker-compose run --entrypoint="python manage.py test" web
```

Comment: You may notice that the command `docker-compose run web python manage.py test` runs fine in the first build (with `command` used in docker-compose.yml). But it fails in this case.

What do you think can be done here? Maybe creating a build_script.sh and adding `docker-compose run web python manage.py test` ?

Comment: I've added an update to my answer. Seems like I was wrong in my original statement. Please let me know if my updated proposal works.

Comment: The command now works, but it produces the same error as the first build: (https://travis-ci.com/github/mformihir/COVID-19-Predictive-Analysis/jobs/362934849)

I'll try updating heroku CLI in Travis now. Also, if you think the question was useful, please, upvote.